# Average in R; Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to have a mean for each year for both the countries. But I am unable to formulate a code. Please help

I was trying the following code but it does not work.

```
Mean <- dt %>%
group_by(year) %>%
summarise(Average=mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Following is the input

```
structure(list(year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2012, 2012), 
India = c(56, 53, 52, 0, 29, 30), Nepal = c(35, 6, 7, 12, 
34, 55)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
dt %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(average_india = mean(India, na.rm = TRUE),
            average_nepal = mean(Nepal, na.rm = TRUE))

   year average_india average_nepal
  <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1  2010          40.2          15  
2  2012          29.5          44.5
```

or

```
dt %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~mean(.x)))

   year India Nepal
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2010  40.2  15  
2  2012  29.5  44.5
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the mean grouped by year of all columns without specifying their headers?

Comment: @AnayaFakar That's my second method after **or**, using `across(everything(),...)`.